# MKMapView : Animate Drawing of MKPolyline Between Locations

Tags: ios, swift, animation, mkmapview, mkpolyline

I have drawn straight line between locations using MKPolyline in MKMapView

```
let locations:[CLLocationCoordinate2D] = ...

let polyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates: locations, count: locations.count)
mapView.add(polyLine)

// MKMapViewDelegate

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        renderer.lineWidth = 4.0
        return renderer
    }
```

[image]

Now I want show drawing animation of line from one coordinate to another instead of already drew lines. Is there any possibility to do that? Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From your array of coordinates draw a poly line between first item and the second say in 0.1 seconds , then draw with the first item to the third and so on until draw with the first item to the last one with a timer you can have animated draw from source to destination

Comment: schedule a timer that runs say every 0.1 seconds

Comment: But it does't help for smooth animation.

Answer (score 0):

1. An array of coordinates will be needed. If you have only beginning and end coordinates, get array of coordinates using below code

   ```
   func getPointsOnRoute(from: CLLocation?, to: CLLocation?, on mapView: MKMapView?) -> [CLLocation]? {
   let NUMBER_OF_PIXELS_TO_SKIP: Int = 120
   //lower number will give a more smooth animation, but will result in more layers
   var ret = [Any]()

   var fromPoint: CGPoint? = nil
   if let aCoordinate = from?.coordinate {
       fromPoint = mapView?.convert(aCoordinate, toPointTo: mapView)
   }
   var toPoint: CGPoint? = nil
   if let aCoordinate = to?.coordinate {
       toPoint = mapView?.convert(aCoordinate, toPointTo: mapView)
   }
   let allPixels = getAllPoints(from: fromPoint!, to: toPoint!)
   var i = 0
   while i < (allPixels?.count)! {
       let pointVal = allPixels![i] as? NSValue
       ret.append(point(toLocation: mapView, from: (pointVal?.cgPointValue)!)!)
       i += NUMBER_OF_PIXELS_TO_SKIP
   }
   ret.append(point(toLocation: mapView, from: toPoint!)!)
   return ret as? [CLLocation] }
   ```
2. Having array of coordinates add rendering of the overlays in MKMapViewDelegate’s delegate method — `mapView(_:rendererFor:)`.

   ```
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
   guard let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline else {
           return MKOverlayRenderer()
       }

       let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: polyline)
       polylineRenderer.strokeColor = .black
       polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 2
       return polylineRenderer
   }
   mapView.addOverlay(polyline) // add it to mapview
   ```

   3. render the polyline in small segments to create the animation effect

   ```
   var drawingTimer: Timer?
   // .... // Somewhere in your View Controller
   func animate(route: [CLLocationCoordinate2D], duration: TimeInterval, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
           guard route.count > 0 else { return }
           var currentStep = 1
           let totalSteps = route.count
           let stepDrawDuration = duration/TimeInterval(totalSteps)
           var previousSegment: MKPolyline?

           drawingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: stepDrawDuration, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
               guard let self = self else {
                   // Invalidate animation if we can't retain self
                   timer.invalidate()
                   completion?()
                   return
               }

               if let previous = previousSegment {
                   // Remove last drawn segment if needed.
                   self.mapView.removeOverlay(previous)
                   previousSegment = nil
               }

               guard currentStep < totalSteps else {
                   // If this is the last animation step...
                   let finalPolyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: route, count: route.count)
                   self.mapView.addOverlay(finalPolyline)
                   // Assign the final polyline instance to the class property.
                   self.polyline = finalPolyline
                   timer.invalidate()
                   completion?()
                   return
               }

               // Animation step.
               // The current segment to draw consists of a coordinate array from 0 to the 'currentStep' taken from the route.
               let subCoordinates = Array(route.prefix(upTo: currentStep))
               let currentSegment = MKPolyline(coordinates: subCoordinates, count: subCoordinates.count)
               self.mapView.addOverlay(currentSegment)

               previousSegment = currentSegment
               currentStep += 1
           }
       }
   ```